# Visual studio 2017 setup project without dependencies

Tags: winforms, fody-costura

I have used [Costura.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) to combine all references to a single exe successfully following [this](https://github.com/Fody/Costura/#costurautility) guide. But when I create a Setup project and **Add**->**Project Output...** it installs all references to the folder.Is it possible to create msi containing only the costura's single .exe? Thanks in advance